# Issue with sorting algorithm and object pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have an object containing some data such as:

```
class Employee{
    private:
         int employee_number;
         // +more objects and data
    public:
        int get_number() {
            return employee_number;
        }
};
```

The objects are stored in a pointer array:

```
Employee* employees[MAX + 1];
```

The first element in Employee is not used, so the algorithm skips employees[0]

The sorting algorithm is called each time a new employee has been added, here is what the sorting algorithm looks like:

```
int to = employees.length - 1;
for (int from = 1; from < to; from++) {
    if (employees[from]->get_number() > employees[from + 1]->get_number()) {
        Employee *tmp = employees[from + 1];
        int i = from;

        while (i >= 1 && employees[i]->get_number() > tmp->get_number()) {
            employees[i + 1] = employees[i];
            i--;
        }

        employees[i + 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't sort the employees array, as this algorithm works well with regular int arrays. Also keep in mind my entire code is written in my own language, so I had to translate into English here.

Comment: your `tmp` member is just a pointer, are you sure thats what you intend? Id expect you need an extra `Employee` object for an in place sort like this

Comment: Part of the assignement was to have constructors reading user input, so if I do `Employee tmp = new Employee;` it will call the constructor, so I would guess I need to bypass the constructor in that case.

Comment: `employees.length` is ill-formed for `Employee* employees[MAX + 1]`

Comment: @eerorika Yes, sorry, should have put something else, in source code it is an integer which represents the next value. such as `int lastUsed = 1`which increases each time a new employee has been created. I thought using .length here would represent the same idea

Comment: What's wrong with just `std::sort` with a lambda predicate? This looks too complex for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to sort the `Employee` pointers in ascending order by the data member `employee_number` (i.e., `employee_number` is the key) of the objects they are pointing to, you could define the following predicate using a lambda expression:

```
auto cmp = [](auto a, auto b) {
   return a->get_number() < b->get_number();
};
```

Then, use the [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) algorithm with the predicate above:

```
auto begin = &employees[1]; // skip 1st element
std::sort(begin, employees + num, cmp);
```

where `num` above is `1` (since you said that the 1st entry is not used) plus the number of `Employee` pointers inserted so far.

---

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve, but if you have the intention of calling `std::sort()` on the array every time a new `Employee` is added to the array, you might want to consider using another container like [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead of an array.